# Error al leer lista en python

Tags: python

Algúno sabe porqué no me funciona el range al tratar de leer la lista, me arroja TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, pero mirando los datos ambos son enteros, lo logro hallar el erros, gracias.

Estas son mis listas:

```
codigos = [3174,3198,3199,3202,3243,3144,3204,3205,3145,3200,3474,2780,2789,2790]
baseAd108 = [('22000239368A', '0171', 'RADICADA', 'S', 3174, '22000', 'YY'),('22000239369A', '0171', 'RADICADA', 'S', 3174, '22000', 'ZZ')]
```

Este es mi código:

```
for row in baseAd108:
    if row[2] == 'RADICADA' and row[3] == 'S':
        if row[4] in range(*codigos): 
            res1 = (row[0], row[1], observ, accion)
            res.append(res1)
```

Me marca el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "miarchivo.py", line 562, in <module>
    Ad108()
  File "miarchivo.py", line 346, in Ad108
    if row[4] in range(codigos): 
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: no le puedes pasar una lista debe ser un int como te indica `range(codigo[0], codigo[1])`

Comment: O si quieres pasar cada item de la lista como argumentos posicionales, puedes hacerlo así: range(*codigo).

Comment: Amigo muchas , gracias así si me funcionó .

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien lo que pretendes, así que, asumiendo que con `row[4] in range(*codigos)` pretendes comprobar si el valor de `row[4]` está en la lista `codigos`, simplemente vale con `row[4] in codigos`.

Si pretendías otra cosa, coméntalo e intento solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Solo requería validar mi lista, la estaba confundiendo con un rango:

```
for row in baseAd108:
    if row[2] == 'RADICADA' and row[3] == 'S':
        if row[4] in codigos: 
            res1 = (row[0], row[1], observ, accion)
            res.append(res1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se utiliza el bucle for para recorrer una lista, row es el elemento de la lista.

Por lo que si usas un índice. Es decir, row[4], con la variable row en una lista con elementos de tipo string no puedes hacer if row[4] in range(*codigos)

Porque la lista codigos contiene elementos de tipo int. De ahí el **TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

La solución es que todos los elementos pertenecientes a las listas fueran de tipo String para que se pudieran comparar de la forma que tu quieres sin ese error de tipo. Un saludo.